# Issue with persistent storage in Azure Kubernetes Service using Azure Disk

Tags: azure, persistent-storage, azure-aks

Not able to set up persistent volume using Azure disk

We are trying to deploy an application on AKS and the application is to use persistent volume. If we use Azure disk, we have noticed if the node having the pod running the application container is stopped / not working , another pod from another node is spinned up but it is no longer accessing the persistent volume.
As per documentation ,azure disk is mapped to a particular node and file share is shared across nodes. What is the way to ensure that a application running on AKS using persistent volume is not lost if a pod/node does not work ?

We are looking for a solution with regard to persistent storage so that an application with 3 pods as a replica set can use an Azure disk persistent volume in AKS.

Comment: Is your application writing to a disk and you want all pods to access the same disk ? Maybe you should create a storage account then all your pods will be able to write/read to a centralized place. Depends what kind of things you're writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure disk to work as the persistent storage volume in AKS, it should associates to the actual node, so it cannot share the files between multiple pods. So if you want to share files and persist files between pods whenever the pods in any node, the Azure File Share is a good way for you.

Finally, all of all, if you have multiple nodes and the deployment has 3 replicas. Then the best way to share and persist data between pods is using the Azure File Share or the NFS.